# How put only 5 buttons per page

Tags: php, pagination, phpmyadmin

Hey guys i did a pagination to show 50 items per page. It works but when I put the buttons, it appear based in all registers. For example i have 1910 items, and is showing 39 buttons per pages so is horrible.

How can i show only 5 numbers buttons 1-2-3-4-5 -> , <-2-3-4-5-6->,  .......  <-10,11-12-13-14-> per page according to the records that are positioned?

Here is the code for the reference:

```php
<?php

$page = 1;
if(array_key_exists('pg', $_GET)){
    $page = $_GET['pg'];
}
        
$q = "SELECT COUNT(*) as conteo FROM Infraccions";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $conteo = $row['conteo'];
}
    
$max_num_paginas = intval($conteo/50); 
$segmento = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM infraccions LIMIT ".(($page-1)*50).", 50 ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($segmento, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    .........
}
        
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
    
if ($prev > 0) { 
    echo "<b><a class='page-link' aria-label='Previous' href='Llista_Infraccions.php?pg=$prev'><-"; 
}

?>
        
    </a></b>
</li>
        
<?php

for( $i=0; $i <= $max_num_paginas; $i++) { 
    echo '<b><a class="page-link" href="Llista_Infraccions.php?pg='.($i+1).'">'.($i+1).'</a></b>'; 
}
                
//Boton 'Siguiente'
if ($page < $max_num_paginas ) {
    echo "<b><a class='page-link' aria-label='Next' href='Llista_Infraccions.php?pg=$next'>->"; 
}

?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$pages = array( 'Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3', 'Page 4', 'Page 5', 'Page 6', 'Page 7', 'Page 8', 'Page 9', 'Page 10' );

// The current page
$current_page = !empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$pages_count = count( $pages );
$max_in_page = 2;
$pagination = ceil( $pages_count / $max_in_page );

$index_start = ( ( $current_page - 1 ) * $max_in_page );
$index_end = $index_start + $max_in_page;

$showing_pages = array_slice( $pages, $index_start, $max_in_page );

foreach( $showing_pages as $key ){

    echo $key . "<br>";

}

for( $i = 1; $i <= $pagination; $i++ ){

    echo " <a href=\"?page=$i\">[$i]</a> ";

}
```